# Angular form won't post to external URL

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

I'm making a site that has a form that needs to do a POST to an external payment provider. However, I need to go through my component's code to check if the user is authenticated first. If not, I need to go through my webapi to update a value. Once the response is received, I can continue with the POST to the external URL. My code look like this:

```
 onSubmit(form: any): void {  
         //for anonymous orders, we need to store the email before we send the form
         if(this.loggedIn){
            form.submit(); 
         }
         else{
             this.cartService.updateUserEmail(this.cart.id, this.email)
                             .subscribe(() => form.submit())
         }
  }
```

If `this.loggedIn` is true, the POST works correctly. It's only when I need to call the cartService that the form.submit isn't working. Sometimes, the console shows an error, "object does not contain a method submit()", other times, I get nothing in the console....it just isn't working.

Here is the opening form tag:

```
<form #cartForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(cartForm)" method="post" [action]="cart.paymentUrl" >
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is the markup for my submit button, as requested:

```
<button type="submit">CHECKOUT</button>
```

Comment: what happens if you `console.log(form)` right before you `updateUserEmail`? Does it have the correct data? How about right before you submit the form in your subscription?

Comment: @Adam doing form.submit BEFORE the call to my service works. Console.log shows me the correct value, yes. In fact, I've debugged this all the way through my .net code. No problems there. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @SteveG. That doesn't work either.

Comment: Is the post still happening in the `else` statement when the JS *doesn't* error?  (I'm wondering if the `submit` event isn't being cancelled in the `else` and you're in a race condition.)

Comment: @SteveG. Even when I don't get any errors in the console, the post still does NOT happen. I don't get it. I can add a console.log statement in the subscribe and I see it logging, but the form never submits.

Comment: Thank you for that. Just out of morbid curiosity, can you try changing to `<button type="button">CHECKOUT</button>`

Comment: @SteveG. If I do that, the onSubmit method doesn't fire.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ngForm` being sent to your event handler does not have a `.submit()` method, so you'll need to get the underlying `form` from either `ngForm` or the `event` so you can use its `.submit()` method.

For this example, I used the `event`.

**Markup**

```
<!-- Note that I added the $event to the handler -->    
<form #cartForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(cartForm, $event)" method="post" [action]="cart.paymentUrl" >
```

**TS**

```
onSubmit(form: any, e: any): void {  
     //Note that I added 'e' and calling the event target's .submit()
     if(this.loggedIn){
        e.target.submit();
     }
     else{
         this.cartService.updateUserEmail(this.cart.id, this.email)
            .subscribe(() => {
                e.target.submit();
            })
     }
}
```

I stripped it down a bit, but here is a [Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E33AaAGSYsJcvlWEVGFV?p=preview) ("Working" as in, you'll notice the failed POST -- after 1 second -- in `console` to www.google.com due to cross-domain issues.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way and tell me if it solve your issue ?

Template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #cartForm ="ngForm" >...</form>
```

Component:

```
@ViewChild('cartForm') cartForm: NgForm;

onSubmit() {  
         //for anonymous orders, we need to store the email before we send the form
         if(this.loggedIn){
            this.SomeService.create(this.cartForm.value, this.cart)
         }
         else{
             this.cartService.updateUserEmail(this.cart.id, this.email)
                             .subscribe(() => 
                                this.someService.create(this.cartForm.value, this.cart)
                             )
         }
  }
```

someService:

```
create(yourModel, cart): Observable<yourModel> {
    return this.http
      .post(cart.paymentUrl, JSON.stringify(yourModel), {headers: this.headers}) 
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch(//handle errors);
  }
```